# Problema codigo sencillo en Flask

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

Llevo unos dias dandole vueltas a unas lineas creadas con Flask y no logro ver en que me equivocado. Se supone que deberia añadir el mensaje en el input vacio con el texto que recoge de 'message' pero me da error, siempre entro en "Warning: Some fields are missing"

En el archivo .py especifico que recoja los datos del formulario como se puede ver en el codigo:

```
@app.route('/processHome', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def processHome():
    missing = []
    fields = ['message', 'last', 'post_submit']
    for field in fields:
        value = request.form.get(field, None)
        if value is None:
            missing.append(field)
    if missing:
        return "Warning: Some fields are missing"

return '<!DOCTYPE html> ' \
       '<html lang="es">' \
       '<head>' \
       '<link href="static/css/orienta.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>' \
       '<title> Home - Orienta2 </title>' \
       '</head>' \
       '<body> <div id="container">' \
       '<a href="/"> Orienta2 </a> | <a href="home"> Home </a> | <a href="login"> Log In </a> | <a href="signup"> Sign Up </a>' \
       '<h1>Hi, How are you?</h1>' \
                '<form action="processHome" method="post" name="home"> ' \
        '<label for="message">Say something:</label><div class="inputs">' \
        '<input id="message" maxlength="140" name="message" size="80" type="text" value=""/>' \
        '<input id="last" type="hidden" name="last" value="' + request.form['last'] + '<br>'+ request.form['message'] + '">' \
                 '</div>' \
                    '<div class="inputs">' \
                    '<input id="post_submit" name="post_submit" type="submit" value="Post!"/>' \
            '<br><br>Previous Posts: <br>' + request.form['last'] + '<br>' +request.form['message'] + \
                '</form>' \
                '</div></div>' \
       '</body>' \
       '</html>'
```

Y aqui esta lo que tengo en el archivo .html:

```
<form action="processHome" method="post" name="home">
   <label for="message">Say something:</label>
   <div class="inputs">
      <input id="message" class="message" required="true" placeholder="message" size="80" maxlength="140" type="text"/>
      <input type="hidden" id="last" name="last"/>
   </div>
   <div class="inputs">
      <input id="post_submit" name="post_submit" type="submit" value="Post!"/>
   </div></form>
```

Como explico mas arriba la idea es que en el input 'last' que se encuentra oculto se vaya añadiendo lo que se introduzca en el primer input 'message' y se muestre luego.

Creo que el error es relacionado con el input 'last' que no me lo esta reconociendo y es el culpable que entre siempre en el bucle que no encuentra los campos.

Saludos y gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo que a la ruta le has asignado los verbos `"GET"` y `"POST"`. Entiendo que pretendes ante un `GET` mostrar el formulario, y ante un `POST` procesarlo para después volver a mostrarlo junto con el resultado.

Hay un problema entonces, y es que la primera vez que cargas la página, con `GET`, el navegador no envía datos (pues los datos sólo se envían en el `POST`), y por tanto el diccionario `request.form` está vacío, y te faltan todas las claves.

Por tanto la advertencia esa de que faltan cosas deberías mostrarla sólo ante el verbo `POST`, y no ante un `GET`. Esto es fácil de arreglar, cambias la condición por:

```
    if missing and request.method == "POST":
        return "Warning: Some fields are missing"
```

Pero entonces nos encontramos con otros problemas, y es que a la hora de retornar todo el HTML que constituiría el formulario, parte de él lo generas a partir de `request.form["last"]` o de `request.form["message"]`, los cuales no existen por ser la petición `GET`, y por tanto producirán una excepción al tratar de acceder a esas claves inexistentes.

La solución aquí es cambiar esos intentos de acceder a esas claves por `request.form.get("last", "")` y `request.form.get("message", "")`, respectivamente, de modo que si la clave existe (porque la petición fue `POST`) la obtendríamos, pero si no existe (porque la petición fue `GET`), usaríamos la cadena vacía.

En definitiva, tu aplicación queda así. Aprovecho para corregir el HTML que creo que tenía un `</div>` cerrado fuera de sitio, y para usar el truquillo de poner entre paréntesis la secuencia de cadenas a concatenar, lo que te ahorra el  `\` al final de cada línea. Te recomendaría de paso que usaras *templates* jinja en lugar de embeber el HTML en el código.

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/processHome', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def processHome():
    missing = []
    fields = ['message', 'last', 'post_submit']
    for field in fields:
        value = request.form.get(field, None)
        if value is None:
            missing.append(field)
    if missing and request.method == "POST":
        return "Warning: Some fields are missing"

    return ('<!DOCTYPE html> '
            '<html lang="es">'
            '<head>'
            '<link href="static/css/orienta.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>'
            '<title> Home - Orienta2 </title>'
            '</head>'
            '<body> <div id="container">'
                '<a href="/"> Orienta2 </a> | <a href="home"> Home </a> | <a href="login"> Log In </a> | <a href="signup"> Sign Up </a>'
                '<h1>Hi, How are you?</h1>'
                '<form action="processHome" method="post" name="home"> '
                    '<label for="message">Say something:</label><div class="inputs">'
                        '<input id="message" maxlength="140" name="message" size="80" type="text" value=""/>'
                        '<input id="last" type="hidden" name="last" value="' + request.form.get('last',"") + '<br>'+ request.form.get('message',"") + '">' \
                    '</div>'
                    '<div class="inputs">'
                        '<input id="post_submit" name="post_submit" type="submit" value="Post!"/>'
                        '<br><br>Previous Posts: <br>' + request.form.get('last', "") + '<br>' +request.form.get('message', "") +
                    '</div>'
                '</form>'
                '</div>'
            '</body>'
            '</html>')
```

Aunque no tengo del todo claro lo que pretendes, al menos no da errores, saca el formulario, y va añadiendo mensajes a la parte inferior a medida que los vas enviando, que supongo que es el comportamiento esperado.

Comment: Muchas gracias @abulafia por la explicación he tomado nota de todo lo que me has comentado y tienes razon, con jinja quedaria todo mas abreviado y un poco mas legible a la vista.

En cuanto al codigo he siguido tus consejos y he actualizado el fichero pero no conigue devolverme nada... como tu bien has dicho lo que pretendo es añadir los mensajes en la parte inferior a medida que los voy enviando. He probado con 3 navegadores, por si fuese algun problema de cache pero en todos me devuelve lo mismo que algunos de los campos esta vacio.

Comment: No sé qué tendrás exactamente en el fichero que estás probando, pero si pruebas el que yo te doy en la respuesta (es decir, que la aplicación Flask sea únicamente lo que ahí aparece), sí que funciona. Observa que no hago uso de ningún fichero HTML externo. La misma función devuelve el formulario necesario. Para probarlo basta dirigir un navegador a la URL `http://ip.de.tu.servidor:5000/processHome`

Comment: Efectivamente `http://ip.de.tu.servidor/processHome` desde aqui cumple a la perfección lo que queria que hiciese. Entonces el error debe ser del HTML que no es capaz de enviar los datos correctamente o algún problema en la llamada a la funcion processHome... Por cierto, nuevamente agradecerte la ayuda por todo.

Comment: No sé muy bien a qué te refieres con "el HTML", pero creo entender que tienes una especie de "formulario inicial" en HTML, distinto del que retorna Flask. No acabo de entender por qué, pero prueba en ese HTML a dar un `value=""` a los elementos `input` que no lo tengan. En concreto a `last`.

Comment: Si, me refiero a un .html inicial que hace la llamada a Flask, en concreto es este: `<form action="processHome" method="post" name="home"><label for="message">Say something:</label><div class="inputs"><input id="message" class="message" required="true" placeholder="message" size="80" maxlength="140" type="text"/><input type="hidden" id="last" name="last" value=""/></div><div class="inputs"><input id="post_submit" name="post_submit" type="submit" value="Post!"/></div></form>` el cual yo creo que esta correcto y nose porque no envia nada a Flask

Comment: `action="/processHome"`, con barra inicial. Y ¿cómo accedes a este HTML inicial? ¿Es un archivo estático en el mismo servidor? ¿Quién lo sirve, Flask también en su ruta `/static`, o bien otro servidor web?

Comment: El caso que ya probe con o sin barra inicial ya que en otros formularios en los que llamo a otro proceso lo tengo sin barra inicial y me funcionan bien. El archivo es estatico que se encuentra en el mismo servidor al cual Flask le especifico que cargue dicho archivo `@app.route('/home', methods=['GET'])
def home():
return app.send_static_file('home.html')`

Comment: Si el documento "principal" lo cargas desde `/home` pero ese contiene un POST a `processHome`, no tengo yo muy claro que el navegador no esté enviando una petición POST a `/home/processHome`, lo que fallaría. Aunque quizás lo haga a `/processHome`, en cuyo caso debería ir bien. ¿Qué problema encuentras exactamente? ¿Te da un error 404 o te responde correctamente pero no ves lo que esperas?

Comment: Cuando envio desde `/home` en la terminal no me devuelve error `127.0.0.1 - - [07/Feb/2019 14:57:04] "POST /processHome HTTP/1.1" 200 -` es como si lo realizase bien pero no muestra lo que yo espero que seria el return del `/processHome` siempre devuelve el `return "Warning: Some fields are missing"`

Comment: Buf! Me ha costado dar con el problema pero lo he encontrado. Ocurre que en tu HTML estático te falta el atributo `name="message"` en el _input text_. Al carecer de `name`, el navegador no envía ese campo como parte del formulario y por eso la aplicación flask se quejaba de no tener todos los datos.

Comment: No me lo puedo creer me tenia desesperado, y efectivamente aqui estaba el error estaba poniendo `class="message"` en vez de `name` me estaba trayendo de cabeza el error, a punto de empezar de cero de nuevo por ver si era error del ordenador. Muchisimas gracias @abulafia por toda la ayuda y consejos que me has aportado y sobretodo la paciencia para dar con el error.